# Broadcasting in numpy with multiple dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have an image with a black background that contains different shapes in different colors. I want to generate an image per shape, in which the shape is white and the background is black. I have been able to do this with numpy, but I would like to optimize my code using vectorization. This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('mask.png')

image.shape
# (720, 1280, 3)

# Get all colors that are not black
colors = np.unique(image.reshape(-1,3), axis=0)
colors = np.delete(colors, [0,0,0], axis=0)

colors.shape
# (5, 3)

# Example for one color. I could do a for-loop, but I want to vectorize instead
c = colors[0]
query = (image == c).all(axis=2)

# Make the image all black, except for the pixels that match the shape
image[query] = [255,255,255]
image[np.logical_not(query)] = [0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You can save a lot on intermediate array data with extension of unique `colors` into higher dim and then comparing against original data array and then using the mask directly to get the final output -

```
# Get unique colors (remove black)
colors = np.unique(image.reshape(-1,3), axis=0)
colors = np.delete(colors, [0,0,0], axis=0)

mask = (colors[:,None,None,:]==image).all(-1)
out = mask[...,None]*np.array([255,255,255])
```

**Approach #2**

A better/memory-efficient way to get that `mask` would be with something like this -

```
u,ids = np.unique(image.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_inverse=1)
m,n = image.shape[:-1]
ids = ids.reshape(m,n)-1
mask = np.zeros((ids.max()+1,m,n),dtype=bool)
mask[ids,np.arange(m)[:,None],np.arange(n)] = ids>=0
```

and hence, a better way to get the final output, like so -

```
out = np.zeros(mask.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint8)
out[mask] = [255,255,255]
```

and probably a better way to get `ids` would be with `matrix-multiplication`. Hence :

```
u,ids = np.unique(image.reshape(-1,3), axis=0, return_inverse=1)
```

could be replaced by :

```
image2D = np.tensordot(image,256**np.arange(3),axes=(-1,-1))
ids = np.unique(image2D,return_inverse=1)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread('0-mask.png')

# Get unique colors (remove black)
colors = np.unique(image.reshape(-1,3), axis=0)
colors = np.delete(colors, [0,0,0], axis=0)

# Get number of unique colors
instances = colors.shape[0]

# Reshape colors and image for broadcasting
colors = colors.reshape(instances,1,1,3)
image = image[np.newaxis]

# Generate multiple images, one per instance
mask = np.ones((instances, 1, 1, 1))
images = (image * mask)

# Run query with the original image
query = (image == colors).all(axis=3)

# For every image, color the shape white, everything else black
images[query] = [255,255,255]
images[np.logical_not(query)] = [0,0,0]
```